# Why does my CSS property for a class not apply?

Tags: css, stylesheet, chromium

I created a table with a specific `class=` indicator to apply customized `CSS` properties while my `stylesheet` looks like:

```
tr td,
tr th.featured {
￼  border: none;
}
tbody.featured {
  border-top: none;
}
```

However, while trying the stylesheets out in Chromium's page "inspector" they seem to work and apply fine but once I add them to my `.css` file, they don't apply. What's the problem here?

Hooops I missed to include the link:
http://spabc.com/drupal/

Comment: probably the style is being overridden by another css file. try to define more absolute path to the elements in your css

Comment: can you provide an example of your html? that would make it easier

Comment: @Alon Hoops I missed to include the link, sorry!

Comment: @JuanC.Hoops, I missed to include the link... see above

Comment: with your code you're looking for a tbody that has a class of featured, which you dont have in your html, change that to .featured tbody

Comment: Just apply !important to everything...  that seems to be 99% of peoples suggestions around here.  And I am clearly being sarcastic... please do not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are having a non ASCII character in your css.
at the beginning of this line:

```
￼  border: none;
```

this character uses 3 bytes, in hexadecimal representation `ef bf bc`, ASCII is just one byte per character.

sidenote: in bash to show the hex representation of bytes next to their ASCII interpretation you can use `hd <textfile>` or equally `hexdump -C <textfile>`.